# How to stop a automated selenium test suite in tfs build. Tests keep running after cancelling Build.

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, mstest, tfsbuild

I am using an setup where we use the Test Agent tasks to deploy a test agent to a target machine and invoke the tests on them. This will also allow us to run UI tests. All is well and good. But the issue is when I want to stop the test, I just cancel the build. The builds gets cancelled.

I am happy with that. But the issue is the Selenium test keeps on running even after the build is cancelled.

Is there something/ some process which I need to kill in the target machine so that the test comes to an abrupt STOP.

Please help me in this scenario and many thanks for your information.

Comment: could you please specify how do you trigger your test, i mean a command or UI prospect of doing it.

Comment: Technically, you just need to kill the test runner process e.g. mstest.exe , nunit-console.exe

Comment: Thanks Buaban. I did not see mstest.exe running in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Test using Test Agent Task is used in a Build-Deploy-Test (BDT) workflow. Cancelling an inprogress build/release with BDT tasks is not supported. If you do cancel, your subsequent builds may misbehave.

Cancelling an ongoing test run queued via BDT tasks is not supported, either.

More information of Usage Error Conditions, please check this page: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/RunDistributedTests/README.md

You can clear the option of Continue on error in Visual Studio Test using Test Agent Task. If the build fails, no subsequent steps are run.

Comment: This is actually quite an issue, Imagine if you have a few thousand Selenium tests, cancelling requires Manuel intervention every time. Does Microsoft document anywhere that "Canceling" the build doesn't actually cancel any running test agents("Not Supported")? You would think that that users would want to be able to stop the test agent without having to login to the server. Now imagine a distributed test/deployment environment with 10 or even 20 servers... ouch :(